# É possível executar um arquivo Javascript e ter o output no console Node.js dentro do Visual Studio IDE 2019?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, console, visual-studio-2019

É possivel no Visual Studio IDE 2019 executar um arquivo javascript e pegar o resultado output no console Node.js que está dentro do Visual Studio? como o Visual Studio Code tem a extensão Node chamada "Node Exec" que possibilita apenas apertando F8 executar um script Javascript e pegar o resultado no Node.js console dessa maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estava pensando, o Visual Studio IDE 2019 tem a mesma função ou plugin? algo como apertar uma tecla/botão/comando e assim executar um arquivo javascript e ter o resultado no console Node.js?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]